# How get variation's stock quantity woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, stock, product-variations

I'm developing a theme for wordpress and woocommerce and need to show a variation's stock.

```
<p class="stock-m13"><?php echo $product->get_stock_quantity(); ?></p>
```

I read [How to get the stock quantity of an article from woocommerce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20244423/how-to-get-the-stock-quantity-of-an-article-from-woocommerce), but this code only show me the global stock quantity, not each variation quantity.

Do I need another function to get variation quantity?
Or it is possible that my code is not completed (I think it because I have used Twenty Fifteen theme and variation quantity is showed)?

I tried to get the max quantity with this:

```
<?php
    foreach ($product->get_available_variations() as $key) {
        echo $key['max_qty'] .'<br/>';
    }
?>
```

And that works, but I don't know if this is useful when the stock goes down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, with this I can take the quantity.
But is not useful.

With this I can prepare a code that make differents sentences, one for each product, and show it when a variation would be selected using jquery.

But this is not good idea. Is not elegant.
I though existed something like

```
$product->get_variation_price()
```

This code return the variation price when is selected.
But

```
$product->get_stock_quantity();
```

not change when variation is selected because show me the global stock.

Can somebody give me an elegant solution?
Or not exists?

**UPDATE**

Finally I used

```
$product->get_available_variations()
```

To get the data.

With this I've generated html code, hidden with css, and I show it when I click on variation's color.

**UPDATE December 2022**

Seems that we have a most current answer on a new comment on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71503746/3877879

Answer (score 19):

Given a variable product with multiple variations in order to get each variation stock quantity:

```
function get_stock_variations_from_product(){
    global $product;
    $variations = $product->get_available_variations();
    foreach($variations as $variation){
         $variation_id = $variation['variation_id'];
         $variation_obj = new WC_Product_variation($variation_id);
         $stock = $variation_obj->get_stock_quantity();
    }
}
```

This is the cleanest way I figured out for WC 2.5, I think there might be better ways in terms of performance but not as clean.

Answer (score 3):

The below code will print all attributes with '**is_in_stock**' variable.

```
<?php
    global $product;
    $product_variations = $product->get_available_variations();

    foreach ($product_variations as $variation)  {
        $var_data = $variation['attributes'];
        $var_data['in_stock'] = $variation['is_in_stock'];
    }

    //List all attributes with stock available or not array..
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($var_data);
    echo '</pre>';
    die;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your way is the correct way to grab a variation's stock.

As long as you are getting the variations fresh from the database every time you need to use its stock quantity then you should be okay with using this method.

*******UPDATEED

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do.  You should just be able to grab both variation stock and send them over to jquery to play with.

```
$product_variable = new WC_Product_Variable($product->id);
$product_variations = $product_variable->get_available_variations();

foreach ($product_variations as $variation)  {
  $stock[$variation['attribute_pa_variation-name']] = $variation['max_qty'];
}
```

Here I'm assigning stock level to an associative array with attribute_pa_"your-attribute-name" as the key

Now I can send my array over to jQuery.

Please clarify if I'm mis-understanding the question.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone else is wondering how to do this when looping through items in a cart, it's just `$cart_item['data']->get_stock_quantity()` under the following example:

```
foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
  $stock = $cart_item['data']->get_stock_quantity();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'get_selected_variation_stock' );
function get_selected_variation_stock() {
    global $product;

    if ($product->is_type( 'variable' ))
    {
        $available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();
        foreach ($available_variations as $key => $value)
        {
            $variation_id = $value['variation_id'];
            $attribute_pa_colour = $value['attributes']['attribute_pa_colour'];
            $variation_obj = new WC_Product_variation($variation_id);
            $stock = $variation_obj->get_stock_quantity();

            echo $attribute_pa_colour . ": " . $stock . " ";

        }
    }
```

By using this hook, you have to find out all variation's stock quantity as well as other variation's product data woocommerce.