# How to display stock quantity of a product in text in woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce, product, stock

I'd like to call the stock quantity of a simple product somewhere in a paragraph. 
For example i'm writing a blog and I'd like to name the available quantity like this:

```
<p>Only <span class="quantity_product_1">
<?php echo $product->get_stock_quantity(); ?></span> available!</p>
```

I've [come across](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20244423/how-to-get-the-stock-quantity-of-an-article-from-woocommerce) something like this to create a function:

```
<?php
    /**
    * Loop Price
    *
    * @author      WooThemes
    * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
    * @version     1.6.4
    */

    if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

    global $product;
    ?>

    <?php if ( $price_html = $product->get_price_html() ) : ?>
    <span class="price">PREIS:<span class="amount"><?php echo $price_html; ?></span></span><p class="stock-m13"><?php get_sku(get_the_ID()); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

And this:

```
<p class="stock-m13"><?php echo $product->get_stock_quantity(); ?></p>
```

Would anyone know to get this done, how i can do this for a specific product (SKU)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer from [Lorro](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-display-stock-quantity-of-a-product-in-a-post):

One should create a shortcode:

```
// usage example: Only [product_stock id="1592"] available!
add_shortcode('product_stock', 'product_stock');
function product_stock( $atts ) {
  if ( ! $atts['id'] ) {
    return '';
  }
  $product = get_product($atts['id']);
  return $product->stock; // prints 22, ie the qty of product 1592
}
```